# Calling event/methods of one form from another form without reopening form

Tags: c#, forms, events

'Form1' and 'form2' are open in mdi. when i press button in 'form1' it should call evevt or methods of 'form2', e.g. like 'checkbox' checked ,refresh grid
for that I have code for form2(child form):

```
public partial class Form2: Form
{
    private Form1 Form1_Obj1;
    public Form2(Form1 Form1_Obj2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form1_Obj1 = Form1_Obj2;
    }
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

for calling events from form1 I have code

```
Form2 obj=new Form2(this);
obj1.chkSortPlace.Checked = true;
              or         
obj1.chkSortPlace_CheckedChanged(null, null);
```

problem is event is call but code in event i.e.assign datasource to gridview is not occur.it will not give error but result is not display grid not refresh

Comment: What do you really want to do? What you do is running fine but I don't understand reopening form when form reopens would you mention it , When it happens.

Comment: You can call Hide() method in form_load event of Form2 if you want to not Open the form.

Comment: Form1 and form2 are open in mdi. when i press button in form1 it should call evevt or methods of form2, e.g. like checkbox checked ,refresh grid.

Comment: I have provided a beginning answer for your post let know more about your question! You mentioned that they are a MDI forms so I think you should take a look at `Form1.MdiChildren` as well

Comment: they are not MDI form.both are child form in MDI

Comment: I think you should manage these forms from their parent , hit a function in parent from Form1 and then respond it in parent form, I think your descriptions are not cute and understanding your real problem is a problem so to me :!

Comment: I really want to help you and am appreciate your efforts in SO. As SO user I suggest you to read high quality questions to learn more about How to release a question to get an answer as soon as possible. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

A trick to call a method of some other forms in c#.Net is to use `Application.OpenForms` here is a sample code

```
    foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)  
            {  
                if (frm is Form2)
                 {
                     //Put your code here.
                 } 
            }
```

Comment: in your code--->if (frm is Form2)
                 {
  here frm.Event  is not allow 
please tell how to call event
                    
                 }

Comment: I think if you just call function that could be enough but again check Public and private attributes off the event any way this solution could be unsafe I just provide this to let you know there some other methods to call different forms but it's not your exact solution.
of course, you should search net more for this issue.

Comment: problem is event is call but code in event i.e.assign datasource to gridview is not occur.it will not give error but result is not display grid not refresh

Comment: could you please release your codes. I could read your codes to understand your prroblem

Comment: please see my Question i written code.if u can change the checkbox value is Checked i.e. chkSortPlace.Checked = true; then also my problem is solved.here checkbox  modifier is Public

Comment: *please see my Question i written code.if u help me to change the checkbox value as Checked i.e. chkSortPlace.Checked = true; then also my problem is solved.here checkbox modifier is Public

Answer (score 0):

Edit: changed the answer because I misunderstood what OP was trying to do.

The reason you are unable to manipulate `chkSortPlace` is because by default all controls that you add to a form are marked as `private`.

Go to Form1, right click on it, select "View Code" and add the following:

```
public bool SortPlaceChecked 
{
    get { return chkSortPlace.Checked; }
    set { chkSortPlace.Checked = value; }
}
```

Then, when you want to change the state of `chkSortPlace` from your other form, simply use the public property you added above.

Comment: problem is event is call but code in event i.e.assign datasource to gridview is not occur.it will not give error but result is not display

Comment: @Ranjeet oh okay. I misunderstood. You wanted to actually change whether `chkSortPlace` is checked or not. Okay, in that case you simply need to add a public method or property to the Form1 class that will do that for you, since `chkSortPlace` is marked as private by default. I've updated my original answer with a better solution.

Comment: please see my Question i written code.if u help me to change the checkbox value as Checked i.e. chkSortPlace.Checked = true; then also my problem is solved.here checkbox modifier is Public

Comment: *please see my Question i written code.if u help me to change the checkbox value as Checked i.e. chkSortPlace.Checked = true; then also my problem is solved.here checkbox modifier is Public